# Issue with database connect

Tags: database

In this section I get the error

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from sug where IDbro='" + ime + "'and AtributValue='+atr+' and [+/-]='+rat+' ", conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
}
finally
{
     conn.Close();
}
GridView2.DataBind();
promenaP();
}
```

I have issue with database deleting error exception

Comment: **WHAT** is the error?? Please post the **exact** and **complete** error..... we can't read your screen nor your mind.....

Comment: Also: [read about using **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) for your future work .....

Comment: You gave us no error message and the code is only partially there. Please give us a complete minimal example the next time you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from sug where IDbro='" + ime + "'and AtributValue='"+atr+"' and [+/-]='"+rat+"' ", conn);
```

add ""

I had similar issue programming android sqlite...